# QuerySet in Django 2.0. doesnt work

Tags: python, django

I had a little break in Django and today I decided to come back to this framework. But now I have a problem with elementary thinks.
I want to complete one of the guides in polish language. I've install Django 2.0 and I created some things like this:

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
    )
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank = True, null = True
    )

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('blogs.urls')),
]
```

app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('title','published_date').first()
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_list.html', {})
```

and post_list.html

```
<div>
    <h1><a href="/">My blog</a></h1>
</div>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
            <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
            <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Prompt do not receive any errors, but when I checking the localhost:8000 I have only a `<h1>` text. I have tried many solutions but still nothing. I don't know why QuerySet in `%for%` doesn't work. Any solutions? Did something change from Django 1.10 to 2.0?

Comment: you need to pass the queryset to the template, add this to your view `context = {"posts" : posts}`  and also pass this `context` to render like `return render(request, 'blogs/post_list.html', context=context)`

Comment: I changed views.py to :from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts}) but still nothink

Comment: add `context`   ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views.py add,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    #Remove .first() as it only returns one object
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('title','published_date')
    #You have to create a dictionary and pass it to render
    context = {
                 "posts" : posts ,
              }
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_list.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Thank You ! Works ! I didn't know nothing about context

Answer (score 0):

The queryset method `first()` returns a single object, the first one in the order. You cannot iterate over a single thing, but you are trying to do just that in your template. Either remove the `first()` and send all the objects, or remove the `for` loop in the template and just output the single object itself.